# SQL Server 2012: How to set up table and row-level security (access control) for x user roles in y divisions?

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2012, active-directory, row-level-security

I have **n user roles** that shall **restrict the degree of access**, e. g.

1. Reader (read only)
2. Author (select, insert, update, delete)
3. Maintainer (e. g. create new tables or views for their organisational unit)

in **each** of our **m organisational units** (divisions), e. g. sales departments for the countries

1. USA
2. JAPAN
3. United Kingdom
4. Germany

which shall **restrict the visibiblity** of tables and data rows (row-level security).

**Question: What is the best set up to fulfill my access control requirements**

- without creating too many logins, DB users or DB roles (e. g. creating the full matrix of n * m is not an option, n + m would be perfect).
- allow users to see their tables to use standard query/reporting tools (views are acceptable)
- to minimize the DB changes required for user changes (I am using an Active Directory)
- to limit the creation of new tables by the maintainer user role to e. g. the (country?) schemas s/he has access to?

I thought of using database roles based on windows AD groups but do not see a way to avoid the n * m explosion of roles (and therefor DB logins to reference the AD groups).

Note: I saw a similar question but it is related to group organisational units into (overlapping) hierarchies (but did not differentiate between user roles):

[SQL Server row level security - many to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678367/sql-server-row-level-security-many-to-many)

I am using the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and user and groups are maintained in an Active Directory...

A solution like described in in the white paper of [Row level security in SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136109/row-level-security-in-sql-server-2012) seems to be too complicated for me (until it is the only option ;-)

Comment: My current idea is one schema per organisational unit + one database role per org unit and role combination (n * m) + ownership chaining in stored procedures and views to achieve row-level security, is there any better solution (n + m)...?

Comment: OK, I have found a good tutorial (with code!) that explains [how to implement row-level security](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2186/how-to-setup-row-level-security-for-sql-server/) with database roles + the IS_Member function + an "access control list" table. This should work but not solve the n*m vs. n+m problem... Has anybody an idea to solve this?